# docker-compose device wildcard

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to pass all video or audio or USB devices to a container.

```
devices:
  - "/dev/video*:/dev/video*"
```

This apparently doesn't work. But I the platform the container runs on, could have 2, 3 or more video sources and I need to pass all these into the docker container.

Anyone an idea, how to make this possible with docker-compose? I don't want to use 'priviledged' mode.

Thanks!
Martin

Answer (score 6):

You can map `/dev` to container, and add cgroups permission for the device.

If directly use docker command, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/#dealing-with-dynamically-created-devices---device-cgroup-rule)

```
docker run -it --rm -v /dev:/dev --device-cgroup-rule='c *:* rmw' ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash
```

You can change the first `*` in above command to major device number if you want to limit to some devices.

For compose, it seems just `2.3` can support this(I'm not sure why 3 not support, maybe need times), see [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#device_cgroup_rules)

```
version: "2.3"
services:
  backend:
     image: ubuntu:18.04
     device_cgroup_rules:
       - 'c *:* rmw'
     volumes:
       - /dev:/dev
```

Comment: What is the `c` in this rule?

Comment: `c` means char device, you may want to have a look for https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/devices.txt